# How to make caret ignore an absolute positioned element in content-editable div

Tags: html, css

Here is JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/hetegodovo/edit?html,css,output

The only difference between these two blocks is their display property value.

```
.output {
    display: flex;    
}

.output.output--block {
    display: block;
}
```

The first one makes absolute positioned `.delete` element "focusable" by caret while moving it with keyboard arrows.

And the second one makes lines breaks ugly.

Setting `.wrapper` element display property to `inline-block` leads to the first scenario.

What I am supposed to do with html and/or css to make it work properly? All markdown is generated by JS but can be modified easily.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? To make it so that the wrapper adapts whether there is the bullet point or not? Can't you just simply make the caret `float: left`?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/esxxm4d6/)?